# xamarin forms unable to show sqlite data in listview

Tags: sqlite, listview, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am struggling to find the answer by myself, using previous Stackoverflow posts, youtube and google searching.
I am trying to learn how to use SQLite with xamarin forms.

Solution connection:

```
using SQLite;
namespace TestSQLite
{
    public interface IDatabaseConnection
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();
    }
}
```

Android specific connection (iOS is identical)

```
using SQLite;
using System.IO;
using TestSQLite; 
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DatabaseConnection))]

namespace TestSQLite
{
    public class DatabaseConnection : IDatabaseConnection
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection() 
        {
            var dbName = "TestDb.db3";
            var path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), dbName);

            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
        }
    }
}
```

And the MainPage C# code:

```
using SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestSQLite
{
    public class ControlledDrugs
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Drug { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
    }
    public class Users
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _connection = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().GetConnection();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<ControlledDrugs>();
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Users>();

             RefreshUsers();
        RefreshDrugs();

            base.OnAppearing();
        }
        async void OnAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
    var user = new Users { Name = UserInput.Text };
    await _connection.InsertAsync(user);
        }

        void OnUpdate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
 async void RefreshUsers()
    {
        var userlist = await _connection.Table<Users>().ToListAsync();
        Userlistview.ItemsSource = userlist;
    }

    async void RefreshDrugs()
    {
        var druglist = await _connection.Table<ControlledDrugs>().ToListAsync();
        Drugslistview.ItemsSource = druglist;
    }

    private void Userlistview_Refreshing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshUsers();
        Userlistview.EndRefresh();
    }
    }
}
```

I know the add to sqlite method works, firstly because a user on Stackoverflow helped me, and secondly a blank cell appears on the listview. But thats the issue, the cells are blank, no matter how many I add, all blank.
I can't seem to physically access the sqlite database on the emulator to open and investigate if the entries are being written or entered as blanks. System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments does not seem to save the .db3 in the emulator My Documents - separate issue, but limiting me to find the answer myself.

So i know the issue is either: 1)when the solution enters the data into the database (as blank) or if 2)the recall of data from the database to be viewed on the listview has the error.
Also, from my code you can probably see I am calling the refresh listview manually (by the user pulling the listview, because I am still learning and observable collection method/approach is a bit beyond me ATM.

Thanks team

UPDATE: Xaml code as requested: Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSQLite"
             x:Class="TestSQLite.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="User Input"></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="UserInput"></Entry>
        <Button Text="add it" Clicked="OnAdd"></Button>
        <Label Text="User"></Label>
        <ListView x:Name="Userlistview" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="Userlistview_Refreshing"></ListView>
        <Label Text="Drugs"></Label>
        <ListView x:Name="Drugslistview"></ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: please show the XAML/code where you're binding your LIstView

Comment: Two things to check to narrow down your search. 1. Place a break point in the RefreshUsers method and check what's the result of the query and see if the properties are filled. 2. The RefreshUsers method is async void so you'r actually  don't know if the method is finished before you call EndRefresh on the listview. I would try to make it return a Task so you can await it.

Comment: I have changed async void to public void but now I cannot set UserListview. Itemsource  to (=) userlist: Cannot implicitly convert type?
Real novice here guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but hopefully this will help someone in the future (it would have certainly helped me!)

I ran into this same problem while working through the Xamarin tutorials on Microsoft's site. The tutorial first had you save a list to files, then changed to using the SQLite database. When I switched I found that adding a new record populated a blank list entry.

The culprit turned out to be in the binding between the data entry page, the list view and the variable names in the class. I had the class defined as:

```
public class Player
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    }
```

When performing data entry I SHOULD have had:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">

        <Editor Placeholder="Enter player name"
                Text="{Binding PlayerName}"
                HeightRequest="50" />

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Text="Save"
                            Clicked="OnRosterEntrySaveButtonClicked"
                            Grid.Row="1" />
            <Button Text="Delete"
                            Clicked="OnRosterEntryDeleteButtonClicked"
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Instead I had "Text = "{Binding Text}" in the Editor. This didn't generate an error on build. I also had an error in the list view. What I SHOULD have had was:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding PlayerName}"
                      Detail="{Binding Date}" />
        </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Instead I again had "Text" instead of "PlayerName". Note above that "Detail="{Binding Date}" is also wrong. The variable in the class is actually JoinDate. The above binding doesn't generate an error, however when the app runs no data is shown. Changing the binding to JoinDate and re-building allows the data to be shown.

My recommendation would be to check your bindings for setting and displaying the data on those pages.